# Easy responsive tabs custom tab activate

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm using Easy Responsive tab [**LINK**](http://webtrendset.com/demo/easy-responsive-tabs/Index.html).. Here 1st tab is active on page load.. but i want to change my active tab to something else other than 1st tab.. I have following code:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="demoTab">          
        <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
            <li> .... </li>
            <li> .... </li>
            <li> .... </li>
        </ul> 

        <div class="resp-tabs-container">                                                        
            <div> ....... </div>
            <div> ....... </div>
            <div> ....... </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/HZ3F4/1/)** page. i want to change the order of activated to 2nd tab. Is it posiible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it dynamically like this

```
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
  <li><a href="#tab1">Responsive Tab-1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">Responsive Tab-2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Responsive Tab-3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then we need to get the hash from the url and apply the correct class:

**JavaScript**

```
var hash = '#tab1',
    lis = $("ul.resp-tabs-list > li");
lis.removeClass("resp-tab-active");
$("a[href='" + hash + "']").addClass("resp-tab-active");
```

Js Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/HZ3F4/5/

Comment: but while trying, im not getting active state on page load.. can you give demo page?

Comment: @Kiran I updated code and added demo too, this is right answer for you please accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not the correct way of doing this. I just send a click to that tab.

```
$('h2[aria-controls="tab_item-1"]').click();
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HZ3F4/2/

Comment: can we set the active tab dynamically?

Comment: @Kiran, sure, tab 2 is identified by `"tab_item-1"` while tab n is by `"tab_item-n"`

Comment: This was my solution too.  It feels a bit dirty, but I don't think there's a way around this without modifying the code, and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

place below function after initializing of your responsive tab.

`setTimeout( "$('ul.resp-tabs-list li:nth-child(2)').trigger('click');",200 );`

you can also use this simple tab script rather than using junk scripts.

see here: http://simple-jquery-responsive-tab.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 1):

Easy Responsive Tabs plugin has a parameter for that in the source code generated by the "tabs shortcode" feature.
In the following code, just move the "active" flag from the first tab to the desired tab:

```
[restabs ....]
[restab title="TAB 1" active="active"]Content of tab 1[/restab]
[restab title="TAB 2"]Content of tab 2[/restab]
[restab title="TAB 3"]Content of tab 3[/restab]
[restab title="TAB 4"]Content of tab 4[/restab]
[/restabs]
```

I know this thread is old, but my answer may help someone.

Answer (score 1):

### Html Code

```
<ul class="resp-tabs-list">
 <li><a href="#tab1">Responsive Tab-1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#tab2">Responsive Tab-2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#tab3">Responsive Tab-3</a></li>
</ul>
```

## Scripts Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
   var slug = '#tab2'; 
   setTimeout( "$('"+slug+"').trigger('click');",50 );
});
```

Comment: Please add a short explanation of your code so people with low knowledge of the involved technologies have a chance to understand and re-use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul.resp-tabs-list > li").removeClass("resp-tab-active");     
$("div.resp-tabs-container > h2").removeClass("resp-tab-active");     
$("div.resp-tabs-container > div").removeClass("resp-tab-content-active");    
$("div.resp-tabs-container > div").hide();
$('ul.resp-tabs-list > li[aria-controls="tab_item-2"]').addClass("resp-tab-active");     
$('div.resp-tabs-container > h2[aria-controls="tab_item-2"]').addClass("resp-tab-active");     
$('div.resp-tabs-container > div[aria-labelledby="tab_item-2"]').addClass("resp-tab-content-active");    
$('div.resp-tabs-container > div[aria-labelledby="tab_item-2"]').show();
```